# How to Call Magento2 Rest API in Ionic2

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm, ionic2, magento2

We have try to Call Magento2 Rest API but we don't understand how to call using 
consumerKey,consumerSecret,accessToken,accessTokenSecret.

`let options = this.getRequestOptions();
    options.headers = new Headers();
    options.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer Customer Token");
    let seq = this.get("default/V1/categories", "", options).share();`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you getting any error messages with your current implementation attempt?

Comment: We need Magento2 API call in ionic2 because now we calling api as simple way define by ionic official website so if you have any function for calling Magento2 API, please suggest a solution,
We are getting "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" Error

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Magento, but from the error message it sounds like a CORS issue. I would recommend doing a search for something along the lines of "Magento 2 CORS"

Comment: Thanks for support